# 'rand' range in Ruby (Chris Pine's "Learn to Program")

Tags: ruby

I'm reading through the book "Learn to Program" by Chris Pine.  In section 7.5 "A Few Things to Try" he has you write a program that has you talking to a grandma that's hard of hearing.  When you shout to her, she should reply "NO, NOT SINCE [year between 1930 and 1950]."

In the hints, Pine writes, "Hint 3: People often ask me, “How can I make rand give me a number in a range not starting at zero?” Well, you can’t; rand just doesn’t work that way. So, I guess you’ll have to do something to the number rand returns to you."

In his earlier section on rand Pine wrote about using rand as rand(x) to set the upper limit.  But from some other resource I used (can't remember what it was), I learned about doing ranges that look like (x..y).  So in my code I just put the following:

```
...
elsif whatusay == whatusay.upcase
   puts "NO, NOT SINCE " + rand(1930..1951).to_s + "!"
```

In my tests this seems to be working fine for producing a random number between 1930 and 1950.  So what's with the hint?  Am I missing/not understanding something?  Has Ruby been updated to allow this since the book was written?

Comment: Either that, or the book was wrong all along. :-)

Comment: You code is wrong. rand picks from the max as well, so unless you want your screaming grandmother talking about 1951, she'll be off in 4,7% of the cases. :)

Comment: In the book (p. 38) Pine wrote "Note that for the weatherman example I used rand(101) to get numbers from 0 to 100."  Are you saying that with a regular (x..y) range you can use the exact numbers instead of having the upper limit one higher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Kernel#rand` has accepted a range since Ruby 1.9.3, so I suppose the book was written before that.